# Google Cloud Endpoint no result via JavaScript Client

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-api, google-cloud-endpoints

I am hosting an GAE Application and try to get Google Clound Endpoints to work. Now everything is setup and tested with curl:

```
curl http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/myendpoint/v1/queryData
```

Returns exactly 1 item which is correct:

```
{
  "items" : [ {
    "id" : "220",
    "timestamp" : "1371475009682951",
    "identifier" : "test1.0",
    "value" : "523"
  } ]
}
```

For no reason the same call through my JavaScript client returns nothing:

```
gapi.client.myendpoint.queryData().execute( function(result) {
        console.log("result: " + result);
});
```

The output I get is:

```
result: [object Object]
```

What am I missing out?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`result` is already a JSON Object and not a string.

With `"result: " + result` you force casting the object to a string and `[object Object]` is just the way this is displayed by default.

For example `console.log("result: " + {"name": "I'm an object!"})` will give you exactly the same output

Try `console.log(result)` instead and you should see the real contents of the response.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just got back to my questions to comment exactly about that cause I just realized myself. Must be the temperature here that makes me blind. :)